# Calloc a Two-Dimensional Array

Tags: c, arrays, calloc

To make a two dimensional array, I'm currently using the following:

```
int * own;

own = (int *)calloc(mem_size, sizeof(int));

for (i=0;i<mem_size;i++){
    own[i] = (int *)calloc(3, sizeof(int));
}
```

However, every time I reference own[i][j], I get an error saying that the subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector.

Comment: `own` should be a `int**`.

Comment: Often it's best to model a 2d array as a contiguous block and use i x rows + j to access elements. Consider this as an alternative.

Comment: To be more precise, this is *not* a 2D array, but only an emulation of such a thing through pointers to pointers. Don't do that if you mustn't. `int (*own)[n] = malloc(sizeof(int[m][n]));` is all you need with a decent C compiler.

Comment: @JensGustedt: you should make that an answer - it is by no means an obvious technique.  In fact, I don't think I've ever seen it used before.  (if you have the time and inclination, it would be nice to expand on what constitutes a decent or inadequate compiler).

Comment: @MichaelBurr, this wouldn't be appropriate as an answer here, the question is more specific than that. And I also did that several times, blogged on it, ... , just spread the word. https://gustedt.wordpress.com/2011/01/09/dont-be-afraid-of-variably-modified-types/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use:

```
int ** own; // int**, not int*
own = calloc(mem_size, sizeof(int*)); //int*, not int
                                      // And remove the explicit cast.
```

Answer (score 7):

> However, every time I reference own[i][j], I get an error saying that the subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector.

That's right.  `own[i]` is equivalent to `*(own + i)`, which has type `int`.  You cannot apply the subscript operator to an `int`.

Note that what your code appears to be trying to create is not a two-dimensional array, but rather an array of pointers.  If that's really what you want then `own` should have type `int **`, and you should adjust the first `calloc()` call accordingly.  If you really want dynamic allocation of a 2D array, though, then that would be:

```
int (*own)[3];

own = calloc(mem_size, sizeof(*own));
```

Note that there is no need then to allocate (or free) the rows separately.

Note also, however, that if you do not ever need to reallocate `own` before it goes out of scope, if you can assume at least a C99 compiler, and if `mem_size` is will never be too large then you can do this even more easily via a variable-length array:

```
int own[mem_size][3] = {{0}};
```

No explicit dynamic allocation or deallocation is needed at all in that case, and the initializer can be omitted if unneeded.  (I include the initializer because `calloc()` performs equivalent initialization of the allocated space.)  "Too large" should be interpreted in relation to the array being allocated on the stack.

Comment: Standard warning that VLAs are allocated on the stack, so a VLA may not be a good idea if `mem_size` is a large number.

Comment: @user3386109, thanks, I have updated my answer to incorporate a warning about stack allocation for VLAs.

Answer (score 1):

Because own is declared as having type `int *`

```
int * own;
```

then `own[i]` is a scalar object of type `int` and you may not apply to it the subscript operator.

You could write the following way

```
int ( *own )[3] = calloc( mem_size, 3 * sizeof( int ) );
```

The other way is the following

```
int **own = malloc( mem_size * sizeof( int * ) );

for ( i = 0; i < mem_size; i++ ) own[i] = calloc( 3, sizeof( int ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrong type for 2-D array - well pointed out by many.

Different suggested solution.

When allocating, use the `sizeof` the variable and not `sizeof` the type.  Less likely to get it wrong - easier to maintain.

```
//int * own;
int **own;

own = calloc(row_count, sizeof *own);
for (i=0; i<row_count; i++){
  own[i] = calloc(column_count, sizeof *(own[i]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int *own = calloc(100, sizeof(int));
```

To build a array
2D array in memory is like this =>
[image]

So it can be accessed using such a formula

```
*(own + rows*y +x)
```

Using this type of array is very simple and open, for example when we have 100 cells from memory and we can make it into an array with a size of 100 divisible.
For example, in 100 homes, a array of this size can be provided =>
[1][100]= *(own + 1*y +x)
[2][50]= *(own + 2*y +x)
[4][25]= *(own + 4*y +x)
[5][20]= *(own + 5*y +x)
[10][10] = *(own + 10*y +x)
Sorry if I was not right because I speak Persian and I do not know much English

---

Example:

```
int *aPtr = calloc(100, sizeof(int));
for(int y=0;y<4;y++){
    for(int x=0;x<25;x++){
        *(own + 25*y +x) = 1;
    }
}
```